# How to write a function prototype?

Tags: c++, function

my question is write function prototypes for

1. A function, isAbleToVote, which accepts the age of a potential voter (as a double). The
   function should return true if the value of the double is greater than 18 and return false
   otherwise.
   I wrote `bool isAbleToVote(double)`
2. A function, named printPrice, to print a product name and its price to the screen. Both
   outputs (i.e., the product name and its price) are passed in as arguments.
   I wrote Void `printPrice(string product_name, double price)`
3. A function, sizeOf, which accepts a string as its argument. The function should return the length of the string.
   I wrote `string.length sizeOf(string)`

4.A function, named getInt, to print the following message to the screen “Please enter an integer”, and to return the value of the user input.

I wrote `cout getInt("please enter an integer")`
Am I write? if not what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You should have some course material that explains all this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did well on 1 and 2, those are function prototypes. Though remember, C and C++ function prototypes are followed by a semicolon (to be pedantic)

3 is close, but string.length isn't a return type. Find the return type that best represents the length of a string (hint check the std::string::length() function or strlen() function).

4 is not a prototype. It is a statement. prototypes are simple the signature, without any code body. Read the requirement again and think of the minimal input and output data for the function. Hint there is nothing wrong with a void function that takes no arguments, if you don't need any input or output values.